# Scope.watch in directive called at beginning angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am building a simple directive, I have a custom element that goes by as

```
<button ng-click="change()">Change owner</button>
<problem id="id" owner="owner"></problem>
```

I want to change the owner of the problem with button click, so here it is in my controller:

```
$scope.change = function() {
    $scope.owner = "12390898";
}
```

And my directive code is as follows:

```
app.directive('problem', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            owner: '=owner',
            id: "=id",
        },
        templateUrl: "partials/directives/problem.html",
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.$watch("id", function(newValue, oldValue) {
                console.log("id ->", oldValue, " --> ", newValue);
            });

            $scope.$watch("owner", function(newValue, oldValue) {
                console.log("owner ->", oldValue, " --> ", newValue);
            });
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        }
    }
});
```

However, the console output is:

```
// At initial load
id -> 1230312  -->  1230312
owner -> 548dfa6accfc105ae415f0e7  -->  548dfa6accfc105ae415f0e7
// After the click
owner -> 548dfa6accfc105ae415f0e7  -->  12390898
```

Why is it called at the beginning? The values are same. Is it the right approach to do the following?: I want to initialize the problem at the beginning with default id and owner, and be able to change the owner later with controller outside.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope):

> After a watcher is registered with the scope, the listener fn is
>   called asynchronously (via $evalAsync) to initialize the watcher. In
>   rare cases, this is undesirable because the listener is called when
>   the result of watchExpression didn't change. To detect this scenario
>   within the listener fn, you can compare the newVal and oldVal. If
>   these two values are identical (===) then the listener was called due
>   to initialization.

This is why the watches are called at the beginning. Once the click happens, the watch is called again because the value changes. On subsequent clicks, the watch function should not be called because the owner value is no longer changing as a result of the click.

If you simply want to allow the owner that is set in the parent scope to pass through to the directive scope, the two-way binding is enough.

If you actually want to react to the value changing, the watch would be an easy option to notify you that the values are changing. The watches as they stand now are not performing any valuable function (i.e. just console.log output), so are just eating cycles in the $digest loop.

To answer your ending questions:

`Why is it called at the beginning? The values are same`

See the docs above that says watcher functions are called at initialization time.

`Is it the right approach to do the following?: I want to initialize the problem at the beginning with default id and owner, and be able to change the owner later with controller outside.`

The problem is initialized with id and owner from the two-way binding setup through the isolate scope. As they change from the outside, they will update within the directive's isolate scope, and vice versa.

Sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5zy4tm51/) without watches.

Answer (score 1):

The listener function inside the watcher is called at compile time, even if the newValue and oldValue are the same. If you don't want the function to be executed when the app loads you can wrap your listener in an if statement like this:

```
$scope.$watch("id", function(newValue, oldValue) {
     if (newVlaue !== oldValue) {
        console.log("id ->", oldValue, " --> ", newValue);
     }
});
```

Hope this helped with something.